# Printing data in debugging context

Tags: elixir

I found Erlang's `~p` format command helpful when debugging: it pretty-prints data into a form that can be round-tripped back into Erlang.

In Elixir, I can

```
require Logger
# ...
Logger.debug("foo=#{inspect foo} bar=#{inspect bar}")
```

and get the effect I want, but typing "inspect" everywhere is a pain and sometimes in my codebase I have to `Kernel.inspect`. I'd rather that it just did the right thing:

```
require Logger
# ...
Logger.debug("foo=#{foo} bar=#{bar}")
```

This doesn't work, because I get Elixir's notion of how to represent `foo` and `bar` in a UI -- atoms and (both kinds of) strings print the same, and maps throw an error instead of printing.

Can I tell Elixir to use Kernel.inspect as the default way it prints things?

Answer (score 1):

Sort of... The way that `"#{ foo }"` works is that Elixir uses the String.Chars Protocol and the to_string implementation of that Protocol.

So, what you can do is

```
defimpl String.Chars, for: TypeOfFoo do

   def to_string(foo) do
      inspect( foo)
   end

end
```

So if foo is a Struct that you've defined somewhere, you can add this to the module you've defined it in. I'm not sure if the default implementations in the Elixir library for the standard types is overridable..

Comment: I think I'd want String.Chars to have `@fallback_to_any` set `true`. Is it possible to change that?

Comment: Not without compiling your own version of elixir, there are good reasons why this is not the default.

Comment: I'd love a link to some of those reasons if you've got one